# Virt Manager - Improving disk image performace

Tags: centos, virtual-machine

I created a virtual machine in virt-manager on Centos 8. I am not using an iso but an existing disk image and when I run it, it runs very slow and takes forever to boot the screen once logging in. I've allocated 5 cpus as well as set the memory size to 10gb but the performance still is very slow. I've looked at other advice on the web and things such as setting the disk bus to SATA, cache mode to none, and IO Mode to native still doesn't help improve performance on this machine. Can anybody recommend anything else I should try?

### EDIT

Here is what I get running virsh dumpxml

```
<domain type='qemu' id='9'>
  <name>centos8</name>
  <uuid>********************</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>10240000</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>10240000</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>5</vcpu>
  <resource>
    <partition>/machine</partition>
  </resource>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='***********'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <vmport state='off'/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='custom' match='exact' check='full'>
    <model fallback='forbid'>EPYC</model>
    <vendor>AMD</vendor>
    <feature policy='require' name='acpi'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='ss'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='hypervisor'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='erms'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='mpx'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='pcommit'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='clwb'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='pku'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='la57'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='3dnowext'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='3dnow'/>
    <feature policy='disable' name='vme'/>
    <feature policy='disable' name='fma'/>
    <feature policy='disable' name='avx'/>
    <feature policy='disable' name='f16c'/>
    <feature policy='disable' name='rdrand'/>
    <feature policy='disable' name='avx2'/>
    <feature policy='disable' name='rdseed'/>
    <feature policy='disable' name='sha-ni'/>
    <feature policy='disable' name='xsavec'/>
    <feature policy='disable' name='fxsr_opt'/>
    <feature policy='disable' name='misalignsse'/>
    <feature policy='disable' name='3dnowprefetch'/>
    <feature policy='disable' name='osvw'/>
    <feature policy='disable' name='topoext'/>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='utc'>
    <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
    <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled='no'/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled='no'/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/mnt/disk4/swb80_64.img'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <alias name='virtio-disk0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x04' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='qemu-xhci' ports='15'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x02' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='sata' index='0'>
      <alias name='ide'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x1f' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pcie-root'>
      <alias name='pcie.0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='1' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='1' port='0x10'/>
      <alias name='pci.1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='2' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='2' port='0x11'/>
      <alias name='pci.2'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='3' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='3' port='0x12'/>
      <alias name='pci.3'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='4' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='4' port='0x13'/>
      <alias name='pci.4'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x3'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='5' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='5' port='0x14'/>
      <alias name='pci.5'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x4'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='6' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='6' port='0x15'/>
      <alias name='pci.6'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x5'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='7' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='7' port='0x16'/>
      <alias name='pci.7'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x6'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='8' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='8' port='0x17'/>
      <alias name='pci.8'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x7'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='9' model='pcie-to-pci-bridge'>
      <model name='pcie-pci-bridge'/>
      <alias name='pci.9'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>
      <alias name='virtio-serial0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x03' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='**************'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <target dev='vnet0'/>
      <model type='rtl8139'/>
      <link state='up'/>
      <alias name='net0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x09' slot='0x01' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/3'/>
      <target type='isa-serial' port='0'>
        <model name='isa-serial'/>
      </target>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty' tty='/dev/pts/3'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/3'/>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </console>
    <channel type='unix'>
      <source mode='bind' path='/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/channel/target/domain-9-centos8/org.qemu.guest_agent.0'/>
      <target type='virtio' name='org.qemu.guest_agent.0' state='connected'/>
      <alias name='channel0'/>
      <address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </channel>
    <channel type='spicevmc'>
      <target type='virtio' name='com.redhat.spice.0' state='connected'/>
      <alias name='channel1'/>
      <address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='2'/>
    </channel>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'>
      <alias name='input0'/>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </input>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'>
      <alias name='input1'/>
    </input>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'>
      <alias name='input2'/>
    </input>
    <graphics type='spice' port='5900' autoport='yes' listen='127.0.0.1'>
      <listen type='address' address='127.0.0.1'/>
      <image compression='off'/>
    </graphics>
    <sound model='ich9'>
      <alias name='sound0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x1b' function='0x0'/>
    </sound>
    <video>
      <model type='virtio' heads='1' primary='yes'>
        <acceleration accel3d='no'/>
      </model>
      <alias name='video0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
      <alias name='redir0'/>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='2'/>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
      <alias name='redir1'/>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='3'/>
    </redirdev>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <alias name='balloon0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x05' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
    <rng model='virtio'>
      <backend model='random'>/dev/urandom</backend>
      <alias name='rng0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x06' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </rng>
  </devices>
  <seclabel type='dynamic' model='dac' relabel='yes'>
    <label>+107:+107</label>
    <imagelabel>+107:+107</imagelabel>
  </seclabel>
</domain>
```

Comment: Can you add information from `virsh dumpxml`?

Comment: running the command virsh dumpxml but i need to enter m domain name at the end. I ran the command domainname and got (none).

Comment: You should get domain name with `virsh list --all` or `sudo virsh list --all`

Comment: I posted the output in the edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked with one of my EL8 machines:

```
# diff -y x y
<domain type='qemu' id='9'>                   | <domain type='kvm'>
  <name>centos8</name>                        |   <name>el8_builder_i686</name>
```

Your domain type is `qemu` that means that it is hardware virtualization and it's much slower than hardware-assisted virtualization like `kvm`.

### EDIT:

#### I'm unable to try this myself (it's not tested!)

But you might try the following:

1. Stop The VM
2. Make clone - just in case, it's always smart to have backup.
3. Use `virsh edit DOMAIN` and change `qemu` to `kvm` in domain type (it's in the first line).
4. Try to start the machine. If it works - well I'm happy that this simple hack worked.
5. If it doesn't work then restore previous value (`qemu`).
6. If machine won't boot then use backup (clone).

Comment: is this something I can change? I don't see a setting in virt-manager to switch over to kvm

Comment: @CodeRich - check edit.

Comment: thank you, that did it. It is way faster now.

Comment: @CodeRich I'm glad that it worked. Thanks for accepting the answer, it means a lot for me :).